# Why do I have two known_hosts entries for github?

Tags: ssh

If I run `git clone git@github.com:some-org/some-repo.git`, I'm prompted with the following:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.113)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
```

Obviously, I verify the fingerprint against the list at https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints/, and respond `yes`:

```
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
...etc.
```

That results in **two** entries being added to my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, both with the same key, both hashed.

If I confirm the key with `ssh-keyscan github.com`, the key matches.

But why do I have **two** entries in `known_hosts`, rather than one?

Comment: where do you see two entries? I see only IP and hostname in your question (which is totally not related to the two IPs in the answer).

Comment: I see two entries in the `known_hosts` file. It was non-existent (i.e. empty) until I answered 'yes' to the prompt. Somehow, git clone over ssh knew to add two entries, instead of the one that I see with ssh-keyscan.

Comment: But still I don't have a magic crystal ball and I don't see what you see in your known hosts file without you adding them to the question.

Comment: I thought that "That results in two entries...with the same key" was pretty clear. I wanted to avoid pasting the actual keys into the question.

Comment: ...particularly since the entries are hashed, and therefore actively useless for answering the question.

Comment: why? it is a public key. But that line contains also other information than only the key. If you are curious, turn off the hashing and investigate more ...

Comment: Ah. I see that I didn't (in the question) clarify that these were hashed entries.

Comment: I have 22 entries for github in my known hosts file :/. Everything is hashed, so can't see what it is for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, the `known_hosts` file contains a list of the hostnames/IP addresses on every line. But this is not used when the hostnames are hashed (for simplification of the matching?) as described in the manual page for `sshd`:

> Alternately, hostnames may be stored in a hashed form which hides host names and addresses should the file's contents be disclosed.  Hashed hostnames start with a ‘|’ character.  **Only one hashed hostname may appear on a single line and none of the above negation or wildcard operators may be applied.**

So to answer your question,

> But why do I have two entries in known_hosts, rather than one?

One of them is `github.com` and the other `192.30.253.113` exactly as you confirmed in the prompt

> Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

If you turn the known hosts hashing off (there is no good reason to do that), you will get only one line such as I have:

`github.com,192.30.252.128 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==`

Comment: `for simplification of the matching?` Not only that. A hash of a hostname list would never be the same as any of the single hostname hashes. Simply because the way hashes are created. :)